# In C++, if a function returns a struct, do I need to delete the struct after using it?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, struct

```
typedef typedef struct _OBJTIME {
    WORD wYear;
    WORD wMonth;
    WORD wDayOfWeek;
    WORD wDay;
    WORD wHour;
    WORD wMinute;
    WORD wSecond;
    WORD wMilliseconds;
} OBJTIME

OBJTIME objTime; //Note, this objTime is modified other function
OBJTIME ObjectParent::returnObjTime() const
{
    return objTime;
}
```

My question is:

1. if another class calls returnObjTime() function, like say:

   OBJTIME t = objectP->returnObjTime()
   I assume a new copy of OBJTIME struct will be created?
2. Do I need to delete the variable "t" when I'm done? will it create a memory leak?

Thanks.

Comment: If you or function you called did not call `new` you have no reason to call `delete`.

Comment: Two typedefs? Is this some kind of black magic? C++. Why typedef a struct at all?

Answer (score 6):

No, you're returning a copy of global `objTime`, both the copy and the global have durations based on their scopes, this means that when their scope end they will be automatically released from memory.

Comment: Every object in his code is local, the copy and the global both have scope duration.

Comment: @LukeB.: Though correct, it's not easy to see that from the answer.  You should edit the wording to be clearer that both have scope/automatic duration

Comment: That's good. It was just that "which has" could have referred to the copy or the global, but not both.

Answer (score 5):

It's a copy yes, but it's not created by `new`, so you don't need to `delete` it.

Answer (score 4):

Answer 1: Yes, a new copy will be created with a lifetime based on the scope of calling the function.

Answer 2: No, you don't need to delete somethin you haven't created with new.

Answer (score 3):

You did not `dynamically allocate` it, you do not need to manually `delete` it. So no, there will be no leak here.

Although, as you said yourself, you are making a lot of copies here, which is obviously a bad idea performance-wise.

If your wish is to return a read-only copy of your object, you could do this:

```
const OBJTIME&
ObjectParent::returnObjTime() const
{
    return objTime;
}
```

Then it doesn't matter that your object weights 100bytes or 100Mbytes.

Comment: Copies aren't always bad for performance. For example, copying a small structure a few times may well be faster than dynamic allocation.

Comment: I was refering to the return value, he could return a const pointer or a const reference.

Comment: @ClementRey not unless he dynamically allocates, or alters the function to pass an output parameter.

Comment: What do you mean? He can refer to a non-dynamically allocated object..? I've added some code, things should be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Here the answer:

1 - You are returning value by **return by value method** ,**return objTime;** and taking it into a local variable, so every time it will be a new local copy "t".

2 - You need not to worry to delete **variable "t"** because you are not allocating memory through **new operator** for "t" it will be deleted automatically once you will go out of scope of the function(**local variable scope is within a function block**).

delete is only requires when you will be doing something like :

```
OBJTIME *t = new OBJTIME
```